# wrong number of arguments with impressionist and friendly_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id, impressionist

I'm getting a `wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1)` error when trying to track the model her views.

**My Model:**

```
class Codetip < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  is_impressionable

  validates :title, presence: true, length: { minimum: 4 }
  validates :body, presence: true, length: { minimum: 4 }
  validates :user_id, presence: true

  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged
end
```

**Codetip controller:**

As https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist suggested on section 4 under usage.

```
def show
  @codetip = Codetip.friendly.find(params[:id])
  impressionist(@codetip)
end
```

**My show view:**

`<%= @codetip.impressionist_count %>`

Next to that ive did everything that the wiki suggested: added the gem, bundled, generated the impressions table and migrated it.

***Update 1***

**Stacktrace**

```
activerecord (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:731:in `count'
impressionist (1.5.1) app/models/impressionist/impressionable.rb:47:in `impressionist_count'
app/views/codetips/show.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_codetips_show_html_erb__4508833467180784211_70228361271700'
actionview (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_view/template.rb:158:in `block in render'
activesupport (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
actionview (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_view/template.rb:348:in `instrument'
actionview (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_view/template.rb:156:in `render'
actionview (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionview (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:42:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionview (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:41:in `instrument'
actionview (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `block in render_template'
actionview (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:61:in `render_with_layout'
actionview (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `render_template'
actionview (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in `render'
actionview (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
actionview (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
actionview (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:103:in `_render_template'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
actionview (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:52:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:144:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:36:in `render'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:43:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
/Users/Etore/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
activesupport (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:43:in `block in render'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:86:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:42:in `render'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:19:in `default_render'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `block in send_action'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `tap'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:183:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
activesupport (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:455:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:27:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:248:in `process_action'
activerecord (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:128:in `process'
actionview (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:190:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:262:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32:in `serve'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:39:in `block in serve'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `each'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `serve'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:724:in `call'
actionview (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_view/digestor.rb:12:in `call'
warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (2.0.0.alpha) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.0.alpha) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.0.alpha) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
rack (2.0.0.alpha) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `context'
rack (2.0.0.alpha) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:214:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call'
activerecord (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:963:in `call'
activerecord (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_record/migration.rb:558:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:71:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:49:in `call'
web-console (3.1.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:131:in `call_app'
web-console (3.1.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (3.1.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (3.1.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.0.0.beta3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.0.0.beta3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `tagged'
railties (5.0.0.beta3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.0.0.alpha) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.0.alpha) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/load_interlock.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
rack (2.0.0.alpha) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
railties (5.0.0.beta3) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
puma (3.0.2) lib/puma/configuration.rb:221:in `call'
puma (3.0.2) lib/puma/server.rb:561:in `handle_request'
puma (3.0.2) lib/puma/server.rb:406:in `process_client'
puma (3.0.2) lib/puma/server.rb:271:in `block in run'
puma (3.0.2) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:111:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Comment: have you added `impressionist :actions=>[:show]` in your controller.

Comment: Always, always include the stacktrace when getting an exception.

Comment: @Pardeep Dhingra No, because i'm using friendly_id and the wiki states that you shouldn't be using `impressionist :actions=>[:show]` but impressionist(@..) under the show action directly. Alltho ive tested the code that you suggested but the result was the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ive figured out what the problem was.

On my show page it should have been `<%= @codetip.impressions.count %>` instead of `<%= @codetip.impressionist_count %>`. This topic can be marked as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

update the condition in gems file as `app/models/impressionist/impressionable.rb`

replace `if Rails::VERSION::MAJOR == 4` with `if Rails::VERSION::MAJOR >= 4`

please refer https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist/issues/212